# Add and remove inputs dynamicly with a other input

Tags: javascript, html

I searched a lot for this, but I can only find +1 -1 solutions.
But I want to set the number of inputs with a other input like this:

```
//Enter the number of inputs (1 is the start-value)
<input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" id="count" name="count" value="1">

//Display that number of inputs (1 at start)
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_1" name="input_1">
```

When the user now writes 5 in the first field, the form should look like this:

```
//Enter the number of inputs (1 is the start-value)
<input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" id="count" name="count" value="1">

//Display that number of inputs (1 at start)
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_1" name="input_1">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_2" name="input_2">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_3" name="input_3">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_4" name="input_4">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_5" name="input_5">
```

How can I make this? MUST I use js?

Comment: yes you MUST unless you want to reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple javascript snippet that doesn't make use of any frameworks:

```
function addInputs() {
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value);
    for (var i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
        document.getElementById('moreinputs').innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="input_' + i + '" id="input_' + i + '" />';
    }
}
```

In this example you have to add a container (div) with id 'moreinputs'. However, when calling this function more than once, it will not work properly (e.g. it can only increase the number of input but not decrease)

Comment: Would be awesome to do this without using any framework! But I need to decrease it if needed, can't that be done somehow?

Comment: Of course it can: actually you just have to set document.getElementById('moreinputs').innerHTML='' before the for-loop.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.. I suck at javascript ^^' [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/equeL/)

Comment: Note that you have to select "no wrap - in <head>" in jsfiddle to get it work. And then, the onchange event is triggered after the input loses its focus (i.e. you click anywhere else)

Comment: OK [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/equeL/1/), but how can I get it to decrease each time? How can I do something like empty() on the container without a framework?

Comment: As I mentionned before with document.getElementById('moreinputs').innerHTML=''

Comment: Ah, now I got it I think: [SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/equeL/2/) All without jQuery, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either you use javascript, or you send the form to the server, where a new html page with all the inputs is generated (e.g. with PHP).

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't want to generate a new page for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must use js to do it dynamically on the spot You have a jQuery tag so I will show an example in jQuery

This is not the best example but it works and it's a starting point

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#master').on('change', function() {
        var count = $(this).val();
        $('#otherInputs').html('')
        for( var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           $('#otherInputs').append(
               $('<input>', {type: 'text'})
           );
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" id="master" value="1">
<div id="otherInputs"></div>
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3pdw9/)

In English this is saying...

When you `change` `#master` I will empty `#master` (`html('')`) loop through and append a new input depending on `#master`'s value

Comment: The jQuery tag was removed(I don't know why xD), but it is ok. Looks fine, thx, will try that!

Comment: Well that's because you didn't ask a question about jQuery

Comment: But I asked a question that can be answered with jQuery

Comment: That doesn't matter. really speaking this is a bad question because you haven't come into any issues or problems you can't solve, but people are still happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/h5RTG/)**. Hope it helps. :)

html

```
<input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" id="count" name="count" value="1">
<div id="container"></div>
```

script

```
$('#count').on('keyup', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var count = $this.val();
    $('#container').empty();
    for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++) {
        var newInput = '<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_' + x + '" name="input_' + x + '">';
        $('#container').append(newInput);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
       function AddField() {
        var count = $("#countetfield").val();
        var i = 1;
        var id = $("#container .testClass:last").attr('name');
        var test = id.split("_");
        id_name = test[1];

        while (i <= count) {

            id_name++;
            var a = '<input type="text" class="testClass" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_' + id_name + '" name="input_' + id_name + '"/>';
            $("#container").append(a);
            i++;
        }
    }

<input type="text" id="countetfield" value="1" />
        <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="AddField();" />
        <div id="container">
            <input type="text" class="testClass" size="30" maxlength="30" id="input_1" name="input_1" />
        </div>
```